# changing the column order of a matrix using MAGMA (software)

Tags: abstract-algebra, coding-theory, magma-cas

I've just begun to use Magma (software). I have several questions.

I am trying to change the columns of a 9x18 matrix according to Random(Sym18). the Random gives me a permutation like p=(1,2,3)(6,9,12,11,7)(8,17)(15,13,4). and I want this permutation act on my matrix. How can I do this?

Comment: By magma, do you mean a software, or an algebraically closed space coupled to an operation?

Comment: I mean software, sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the magma documentation to be thorough but hard to search. Google usually does a good job:

https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Amagma.maths.usyd.edu.au+permutation+matrix

http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1705

If `m` is your matrix and `p` is your permutation, then `m^p` is the result of applying `p` to `m`. However, there is a catch. If `m` is an $r \times c$ matrix, then `p` restricted to $\{1,\ldots,r\}$ permutes the rows, and `p` restricted to $\{r+1,\ldots,r+c\}$ permutes the columns.

```
> m:=RandomMatrix(GF(2),9,18);
> symc:=Sym({NumberOfRows(m)+1..NumberOfRows(m)+NumberOfColumns(m)});
> p:=Random(symc);
> p,m,m^p;
(10, 18, 15, 24, 22, 14, 12, 25, 13, 20, 23, 19, 17, 27, 21, 26, 11, 16)

[1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1]
[1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1]
[1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0]
[0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1]
[1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0]
[0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1]

[1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0]
[1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
[1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1]
[1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1]
[1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
[1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1]
[1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1]
```

Comment: thanks. it really helps me.